# Why my bzm uploader requests me update taurus?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter, taurus

I'm executing my test plan normally, using the plugin of blazemeter, but when I want to see my report in blazemeter, it requests me upgrade taurus, but I never used it for my executions.
[image]

I try to execute my test plan and see my report on blazemeter. I expect to see correctly my report.

Answer (score 0):

This question should rather go to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket), most probably [BlazeMeter API](https://api.blazemeter.com/performance/#introduction) has changed and the plugin doesn't work with the new API anymore. Someone needs to update the plugin.

As a workaround you can use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool, it supports running existing JMeter tests so instead of [running JMeter in non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx ...
```

you can [do the same using Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/BlazemeterReporter/):

```
bzt test.jmx -report
```